# Trying to display regression outputs in Rmarkdown in Latex

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, stargazer

Hi all!
I'm currently working on a paper for my university. The task is to run some regressions on a dataset and compile all results in an rmarkdown file. It should be noted that this is my first time working with R, so if the following question is really stupid, I apologize in advance. ;-)

My problem relates to the display of the regression outputs in Rmarkdown. I want to have them in Latex but somehow it won't work. 
I tried to replicate this code https://www.r-statistics.com/tag/stargazer/ but when I enter it I get the following output (this happens both in the console and in Rmarkdown):

[image]

When I manually enter Latex in the Rmarkdown document with the $ notation, for instance to include formulas, it works just fine so I'm a bit puzzled.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious but I can't quite put my finger on it. In any event, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried `results = 'asis'` in the code chunk; i.e., at the very beginning of the code chunk, type in `<<results='asis'>>=`?

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it for me. Looks beautiful now!